# How to do a custom auto-complete textbox for firefox toolbar

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

**UPDATE: I found a solution**

I had to do exactly as follows:

In the extension dir I created a new dir named "components".

Inside that dir I create a js file with my custom auto-complete name, in this case "simpleautocomplete.js".
The content of that js file is:

```
/*
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_implement_custom_autocomplete_search_component
 */
const Ci = Components.interfaces;

const CLASS_ID = Components.ID("6224daa1-71a2-4d1a-ad90-01ca1c08e323");
const CLASS_NAME = "Simple AutoComplete";
const CONTRACT_ID = "@mozilla.org/autocomplete/search;1?name=simple-autocomplete";

try{
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
} catch (x) {
}


// Implements nsIAutoCompleteResult
function SimpleAutoCompleteResult(searchString, searchResult,
                                  defaultIndex, errorDescription,
                                  results, comments) {
  this._searchString = searchString;
  this._searchResult = searchResult;
  this._defaultIndex = defaultIndex;
  this._errorDescription = errorDescription;
  this._results = results;
  this._comments = comments;
}

SimpleAutoCompleteResult.prototype = {
  _searchString: "",
  _searchResult: 0,
  _defaultIndex: 0,
  _errorDescription: "",
  _results: [],
  _comments: [],

    getLabelAt: function(index) { return this._results[index]; },

  /**
   * The original search string
   */
  get searchString() {
    return this._searchString;
  },

  /**
   * The result code of this result object, either:
   *         RESULT_IGNORED   (invalid searchString)
   *         RESULT_FAILURE   (failure)
   *         RESULT_NOMATCH   (no matches found)
   *         RESULT_SUCCESS   (matches found)
   */
  get searchResult() {
    return this._searchResult;
  },

  /**
   * Index of the default item that should be entered if none is selected
   */
  get defaultIndex() {
    return this._defaultIndex;
  },

  /**
   * A string describing the cause of a search failure
   */
  get errorDescription() {
    return this._errorDescription;
  },

  /**
   * The number of matches
   */
  get matchCount() {
    return this._results.length;
  },

  /**
   * Get the value of the result at the given index
   */
  getValueAt: function(index) {
    return this._results[index];
  },

  /**
   * Get the comment of the result at the given index
   */
  getCommentAt: function(index) {
    return this._comments[index];
  },

  /**
   * Get the style hint for the result at the given index
   */
  getStyleAt: function(index) {
    if (!this._comments[index])
      return null;  // not a category label, so no special styling

    if (index == 0)
      return "suggestfirst";  // category label on first line of results

    return "suggesthint";   // category label on any other line of results
  },

  /**
   * Get the image for the result at the given index
   * The return value is expected to be an URI to the image to display
   */
  getImageAt : function (index) {
    return "";
  },

  /**
   * Remove the value at the given index from the autocomplete results.
   * If removeFromDb is set to true, the value should be removed from
   * persistent storage as well.
   */
  removeValueAt: function(index, removeFromDb) {
    this._results.splice(index, 1);
    this._comments.splice(index, 1);
  },

  QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
    if (!aIID.equals(Ci.nsIAutoCompleteResult) && !aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports))
        throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE;
    return this;
  }
};


// Implements nsIAutoCompleteSearch
function SimpleAutoCompleteSearch() {
}

SimpleAutoCompleteSearch.prototype = {
    classID: CLASS_ID,
    classDescription: CLASS_NAME,
    contractID: CONTRACT_ID,

  /*
   * Search for a given string and notify a listener (either synchronously
   * or asynchronously) of the result
   *
   * @param searchString - The string to search for
   * @param searchParam - An extra parameter
   * @param previousResult - A previous result to use for faster searchinig
   * @param listener - A listener to notify when the search is complete
   */
  startSearch: function(searchString, searchParam, result, listener) {
    // This autocomplete source assumes the developer attached a JSON string
    // to the the "autocompletesearchparam" attribute or "searchParam" property
    // of the <textbox> element. The JSON is converted into an array and used
    // as the source of match data. Any values that match the search string
    // are moved into temporary arrays and passed to the AutoCompleteResult
    if (searchParam.length > 0) {
      var nativeJSON = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/dom/json;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIJSON);
      var searchResults = nativeJSON.decode(searchParam);
      var results = [];
      var comments = [];
      for (i=0; i<searchResults.length; i++) {
        if (searchResults[i].value.indexOf(searchString) == 0) {
          results.push(searchResults[i].value);
          if (searchResults[i].comment)
            comments.push(searchResults[i].comment);
          else
            comments.push(null);
        }
      }
      var newResult = new SimpleAutoCompleteResult(searchString, Ci.nsIAutoCompleteResult.RESULT_SUCCESS, 0, "", results, comments);
      listener.onSearchResult(this, newResult);
    }
  },

  /*
   * Stop an asynchronous search that is in progress
   */
  stopSearch: function() {
  },
    
  QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
    if (!aIID.equals(Ci.nsIAutoCompleteSearch) && !aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports))
        throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE;
    return this;
  },
  _QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Components.interfaces.nsIAutoCompleteSearch])
};

// Factory
var SimpleAutoCompleteSearchFactory = {
  singleton: null,
  createInstance: function (aOuter, aIID) {
    if (aOuter != null)
      throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_AGGREGATION;
    if (this.singleton == null)
      this.singleton = new SimpleAutoCompleteSearch();
    return this.singleton.QueryInterface(aIID);
  }
};

// Module
var SimpleAutoCompleteSearchModule = {
  registerSelf: function(aCompMgr, aFileSpec, aLocation, aType) {
    aCompMgr = aCompMgr.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIComponentRegistrar);
    aCompMgr.registerFactoryLocation(CLASS_ID, CLASS_NAME, CONTRACT_ID, aFileSpec, aLocation, aType);
  },

  unregisterSelf: function(aCompMgr, aLocation, aType) {
    aCompMgr = aCompMgr.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIComponentRegistrar);
    aCompMgr.unregisterFactoryLocation(CLASS_ID, aLocation);        
  },
  
  getClassObject: function(aCompMgr, aCID, aIID) {
    if (!aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIFactory))
      throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;

    if (aCID.equals(CLASS_ID))
      return SimpleAutoCompleteSearchFactory;

    throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE;
  },

  canUnload: function(aCompMgr) { return true; }
};

// Module initialization
function NSGetModule(aCompMgr, aFileSpec) { return SimpleAutoCompleteSearchModule; }

if (XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory){
    var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([SimpleAutoCompleteSearch]);
}
```

I added this code to chrome.manifest:

```
component {6224daa1-71a2-4d1a-ad90-01ca1c08e323} components/simpleautocomplete.js
contract @mozilla.org/autocomplete/search;1?name=simple-autocomplete {6224daa1-71a2-4d1a-ad90-01ca1c08e323}
```

In the xul file I added:

```
<textbox type="autocomplete" autocompletesearch="simple-autocomplete"   
autocompletesearchparam='[{"value":"param1"},{"value":"param2"}]' />
```

**important note:** when setting the `autocompletesearchparam` attribute the assignment has to be insind two single quotes and not double quotes. only the values inside has to be in double quotes as in the xul above.

and that's it.

When I tested my extension and typed 'p' in the auto-complete textbox the words "param1" and "param2" poped-up.

I could also set the params in the js file as follows:

```
var searchTextField = document.getElementById("searchTextField");
var param1 = "Param1", param2 = "Param2";
paramsToSet = "[";

paramsToSet += "{\"value\" : \"" + param1 + "\"},";
paramsToSet += "{\"value\" : \"" + param2 + "\"},";

paramsToSet = paramsToSet.substring(0, paramsToSet.length-1); // to remove the last ","
paramsToSet += "]";
paramsToSet = paramsToSet.toLowerCase(); // important!
searchTextField.setAttribute("autocompletesearchparam", paramsToSet);
```

**note1:** notice that the auto-complete textbox only accepts text in small letters.

**note2:** if setting the params to the textbox is dynamically and taking some time, for example - when the client is typing in the textbox and the typed text is sent to a server so the response containing the params will be attached to the textbox, and this process is taking some time (about a second or half), then the popup auto-complete won't popup because it's `autocompletesearchparam` was empty when the client started to type. In this case it is possible to force the auto-complete to popup when you have the params to set in the textbox like this:

```
searchTextField.open = true;
```

Comment: So you copied a bunch of code you don't understand, pasted it into a file, and you're surprised it doesn't work?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you should put the solution in an answer and mark it as accepted, since this is showing as unanswered

Comment: @FilipeSilva you are right, fixed it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Found the solution by myself, hope it will helps someone.

I had to do exactly as follows:

In the extension dir I created a new dir named "components".

Inside that dir I create a js file with my custom auto-complete name, in this case "simpleautocomplete.js". The content of that js file is:

```
/*
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_implement_custom_autocomplete_search_component
 */
const Ci = Components.interfaces;

const CLASS_ID = Components.ID("6224daa1-71a2-4d1a-ad90-01ca1c08e323");
const CLASS_NAME = "Simple AutoComplete";
const CONTRACT_ID = "@mozilla.org/autocomplete/search;1?name=simple-autocomplete";

try{
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
} catch (x) {
}


// Implements nsIAutoCompleteResult
function SimpleAutoCompleteResult(searchString, searchResult,
                                  defaultIndex, errorDescription,
                                  results, comments) {
  this._searchString = searchString;
  this._searchResult = searchResult;
  this._defaultIndex = defaultIndex;
  this._errorDescription = errorDescription;
  this._results = results;
  this._comments = comments;
}

SimpleAutoCompleteResult.prototype = {
  _searchString: "",
  _searchResult: 0,
  _defaultIndex: 0,
  _errorDescription: "",
  _results: [],
  _comments: [],

    getLabelAt: function(index) { return this._results[index]; },

  /**
   * The original search string
   */
  get searchString() {
    return this._searchString;
  },

  /**
   * The result code of this result object, either:
   *         RESULT_IGNORED   (invalid searchString)
   *         RESULT_FAILURE   (failure)
   *         RESULT_NOMATCH   (no matches found)
   *         RESULT_SUCCESS   (matches found)
   */
  get searchResult() {
    return this._searchResult;
  },

  /**
   * Index of the default item that should be entered if none is selected
   */
  get defaultIndex() {
    return this._defaultIndex;
  },

  /**
   * A string describing the cause of a search failure
   */
  get errorDescription() {
    return this._errorDescription;
  },

  /**
   * The number of matches
   */
  get matchCount() {
    return this._results.length;
  },

  /**
   * Get the value of the result at the given index
   */
  getValueAt: function(index) {
    return this._results[index];
  },

  /**
   * Get the comment of the result at the given index
   */
  getCommentAt: function(index) {
    return this._comments[index];
  },

  /**
   * Get the style hint for the result at the given index
   */
  getStyleAt: function(index) {
    if (!this._comments[index])
      return null;  // not a category label, so no special styling

    if (index == 0)
      return "suggestfirst";  // category label on first line of results

    return "suggesthint";   // category label on any other line of results
  },

  /**
   * Get the image for the result at the given index
   * The return value is expected to be an URI to the image to display
   */
  getImageAt : function (index) {
    return "";
  },

  /**
   * Remove the value at the given index from the autocomplete results.
   * If removeFromDb is set to true, the value should be removed from
   * persistent storage as well.
   */
  removeValueAt: function(index, removeFromDb) {
    this._results.splice(index, 1);
    this._comments.splice(index, 1);
  },

  QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
    if (!aIID.equals(Ci.nsIAutoCompleteResult) && !aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports))
        throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE;
    return this;
  }
};


// Implements nsIAutoCompleteSearch
function SimpleAutoCompleteSearch() {
}

SimpleAutoCompleteSearch.prototype = {
    classID: CLASS_ID,
    classDescription: CLASS_NAME,
    contractID: CONTRACT_ID,

  /*
   * Search for a given string and notify a listener (either synchronously
   * or asynchronously) of the result
   *
   * @param searchString - The string to search for
   * @param searchParam - An extra parameter
   * @param previousResult - A previous result to use for faster searchinig
   * @param listener - A listener to notify when the search is complete
   */
  startSearch: function(searchString, searchParam, result, listener) {
    // This autocomplete source assumes the developer attached a JSON string
    // to the the "autocompletesearchparam" attribute or "searchParam" property
    // of the <textbox> element. The JSON is converted into an array and used
    // as the source of match data. Any values that match the search string
    // are moved into temporary arrays and passed to the AutoCompleteResult
    if (searchParam.length > 0) {
      var nativeJSON = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/dom/json;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIJSON);
      var searchResults = nativeJSON.decode(searchParam);
      var results = [];
      var comments = [];
      for (i=0; i<searchResults.length; i++) {
        if (searchResults[i].value.indexOf(searchString) == 0) {
          results.push(searchResults[i].value);
          if (searchResults[i].comment)
            comments.push(searchResults[i].comment);
          else
            comments.push(null);
        }
      }
      var newResult = new SimpleAutoCompleteResult(searchString, Ci.nsIAutoCompleteResult.RESULT_SUCCESS, 0, "", results, comments);
      listener.onSearchResult(this, newResult);
    }
  },

  /*
   * Stop an asynchronous search that is in progress
   */
  stopSearch: function() {
  },

  QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
    if (!aIID.equals(Ci.nsIAutoCompleteSearch) && !aIID.equals(Ci.nsISupports))
        throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE;
    return this;
  },
  _QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Components.interfaces.nsIAutoCompleteSearch])
};

// Factory
var SimpleAutoCompleteSearchFactory = {
  singleton: null,
  createInstance: function (aOuter, aIID) {
    if (aOuter != null)
      throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_AGGREGATION;
    if (this.singleton == null)
      this.singleton = new SimpleAutoCompleteSearch();
    return this.singleton.QueryInterface(aIID);
  }
};

// Module
var SimpleAutoCompleteSearchModule = {
  registerSelf: function(aCompMgr, aFileSpec, aLocation, aType) {
    aCompMgr = aCompMgr.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIComponentRegistrar);
    aCompMgr.registerFactoryLocation(CLASS_ID, CLASS_NAME, CONTRACT_ID, aFileSpec, aLocation, aType);
  },

  unregisterSelf: function(aCompMgr, aLocation, aType) {
    aCompMgr = aCompMgr.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIComponentRegistrar);
    aCompMgr.unregisterFactoryLocation(CLASS_ID, aLocation);        
  },

  getClassObject: function(aCompMgr, aCID, aIID) {
    if (!aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIFactory))
      throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;

    if (aCID.equals(CLASS_ID))
      return SimpleAutoCompleteSearchFactory;

    throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE;
  },

  canUnload: function(aCompMgr) { return true; }
};

// Module initialization
function NSGetModule(aCompMgr, aFileSpec) { return SimpleAutoCompleteSearchModule; }

if (XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory){
    var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([SimpleAutoCompleteSearch]);
}
```

I added this code to chrome.manifest:

```
component {6224daa1-71a2-4d1a-ad90-01ca1c08e323} components/simpleautocomplete.js
contract @mozilla.org/autocomplete/search;1?name=simple-autocomplete {6224daa1-71a2-4d1a-ad90-01ca1c08e323}
```

In the xul file I added:

```
<textbox type="autocomplete" autocompletesearch="simple-autocomplete"   
autocompletesearchparam='[{"value":"param1"},{"value":"param2"}]' />
```

important note: when setting the autocompletesearchparam attribute the assignment has to be insind two single quotes and not double quotes. only the values inside has to be in double quotes as in the xul above.

and that's it.

When I tested my extension and typed 'p' in the auto-complete textbox the words "param1" and "param2" poped-up.

I could also set the params in the js file as follows:

```
var searchTextField = document.getElementById("searchTextField");
var param1 = "Param1", param2 = "Param2";
paramsToSet = "[";

paramsToSet += "{\"value\" : \"" + param1 + "\"},";
paramsToSet += "{\"value\" : \"" + param2 + "\"},";

paramsToSet = paramsToSet.substring(0, paramsToSet.length-1); // to remove the last ","
paramsToSet += "]";
paramsToSet = paramsToSet.toLowerCase(); // important!
searchTextField.setAttribute("autocompletesearchparam", paramsToSet);
```

note1: notice that the auto-complete textbox only accepts text in small letters.

note2: if setting the params to the textbox is dynamically and taking some time, for example - when the client is typing in the textbox and the typed text is sent to a server so the response containing the params will be attached to the textbox, and this process is taking some time (about a second or half), then the popup auto-complete won't popup because it's autocompletesearchparam was empty when the client started to type. In this case it is possible to force the auto-complete to popup when you have the params to set in the textbox like this:

```
searchTextField.open = true;
```

Comment: Thanks remi, you have saved a lot of time and effort of mine. :)

Comment: Hi Remi, Thanks for this useful post. I have one requirement in which I need to select the value from the searched list, and show in the textbox. So, that I can fire the event for that particular searched selection. Can you please advice me how to achieve that. Thanks in Advance, Subh